# Double colons in Ruby's class definition

Tags: ruby, class, declaration

I saw the below declaration in some program.

```
class Animal::Cat < Animal
```

What do these double colons mean?

Does it mean that the Cat class is in the Animal namespace?

Otherwise, the class name itself is Animal::Cat?

Answer (score 4):

It's another (I think neater) way of writing:

```
module Animal
  class Cat
  end
end
```

Alternatively, if you were in the class Dog and saw:

```
class Dog
  def new_cat
    ::Cat.new
  end
end
```

You would know you were talking about the Cat class, and not the Dog::Cat class